# How to get the path of a file upload on ipywidgets?

Tags: python, ipywidgets

How can I get the actual path of the file uploaded from the `FileUpload` widget?  In my case, I am uploading a binary file and just need to know where it is so I can process it using an internal application.

When I iterate on the `FileUpload` value I see there is a file name as a key and a `dict` as the value:

```py
up_value = self.widgets['file_upload'].value
for file_name, file_dict in up_value.items():
    print(file_dict.keys()) # -> dict_keys(['metadata', 'content'])
    print(file_dict['metadata'].keys()) # -> dict_keys(['name', 'type', 'size', 'lastModified'])
```

I know the content of the file is uploaded but really don't need that.  Also not sure how I would pass that content to my internal processing application.  I just want to create a `dict` that stores the filename as a key and the file path as the value.

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once 'uploaded', the file exists as data in memory, so there is no concept of the originating 'path' in the widget.

If you want to read or write the file, access the `up_value.value[0].content` attribute. Your processing application needs to be able to handle bytes input, or you could wrap the data in a BytesIO object.

Comment: I agree with your answer and I did save the content.  Seems like keeping the original file path is a simple thing if the file name is saved.  Perhaps there needs to be a file selection widget.

Comment: There is a tkinter implementation that might be useful, I think I used it in the past with moderate success. https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/162920/file-selection-button-for-jupyter-notebook